# Error in UseMethod("droplevels") when using ggpredict to plot a daily diary study

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot values of stress over time in a daily diary study. I keep getting the error

> Error in UseMethod("droplevels") :
> no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "Date".

Here is my code. The error occurs after the `ggpredict` line.

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
library(emmeans)
library(ggeffects)
library(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)

dat$date <- as.Date(dat$date)
dat$participant <- as.factor(dat$participant)

#1 stress

stress <- lmer(stress ~ date + (1 | participant), data = dat, REML = F)

summary(stress) #summary of model output

emmeans(stress, ~date) #estimated marginal means

ggpredict(stress, ~date) %>% plot()

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(y=stress, x=date, group=participant, color=participant)) + 
     geom_point() + geom_smooth(method='glm', se=FALSE)
```

My professor helped me with this and this is mostly his code. It worked on his computer but for some reason it is not working on mine.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can improve your question by (1) adding a [mcve] (see my answer for an example); (2) making your code more minimal, e.g. by dropping all of the package-loading (emmeans, tidyverse, lubridate) that's not actually required for your example ...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't hard to replicate.  You can't use a Date-type object in a regression model (or at least you can't rely on it working for everything you want to do).

```
library(lme4)
## `sleepstudy` is a built-in object in the lme4 package.
## Days is numeric, make a date out of it ...
ss <- transform(sleepstudy, date = Days + as.Date("2023-05-01")) 
m <- lmer(Reaction ~ date + (1|Subject), ss)
library(ggeffects)
ggpredict(m, ~date)
```

> Error in UseMethod("droplevels") :
> no applicable method for 'droplevels' applied to an object of class "Date"

You could make the date variable into a factor:

```r
ss$fdate <- factor(ss$date)
m2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ fdate + (1|Subject), ss)
ggpredict(m2)
```

This does mean that if you want fancy date-formatted axes in ggplot you'll have to do some more work ...

PS without lots more information, there's no way to know for sure why the exact same code worked on your advisor's computer (if it really did, i.e. if there wasn't some other step left out or added by mistake ...)